# Fouriertransform : Determine the inverse Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Determine the inverse Fourier transform to

$$F(ω) = \frac{1}{(ω^2 + 4)(ω^2 + 9)}$$

using

a) Partial fractions, and then using the Fourier Transform table.

b) Convolution.

I don't know to to solve it :( please help.

Comment: I edited the problem to make it $\omega^{2}$ in the denominator (I assume that is what $\omega 2$ meant). Also, you'll have to tell us what you have tried or no one is going to help you. Make an edit to your post that includes this. Also include what your definition of the Fourier Transform is.

Comment: just tell me the first step and i will do the rest :)

Comment: It doesn't work like that. The way to solve has already been given to you in the question, look up partial fractions and fourier transforms, or read other peoples previous questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT 1:**

For partial fraction expansion, we have

$$\frac{1}{(\omega^2+4)(\omega^2+9)}=\frac15\left(\frac{1}{\omega^2+4}-\frac{1}{\omega^2+9}\right)$$

---

**HINT 2:**

For using the convolution theorem, note that

$$\mathscr{F}(f(\omega)g(\omega))=\mathscr{F}(f(\omega))*\mathscr{F}(g(\omega))$$

where here, $f(\omega)=\frac{1}{\omega^2+4}$ and $g(\omega)=\frac{1}{\omega^2+9}$.

Here we define the Fourier Transform as

$$\mathscr{F}(f(\omega))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\omega)e^{i2\pi \omega t}\,d\omega$$

Comment: thank you for the hints, they are very usefull for me. so i got ===> (pie^(2abs(-5w)))/10   for f(t)    and for g(t) i got ===> (2pie^(2abs(-5w)))/45  is that correct ?  (i used the table)

Comment: @user2393690 You're welcome! My pleasure.  Pleased to hear the this was useful. I cannot read the answer you provided in the comment.  I suggest pursuing using the partial fraction expansion also.

Comment: i get help by my teacher, thank you anyway.  @Dr. MV

Comment: You're quite welcome.